# Problemas al ejecutar consultas mysql (NODE) dentro de un for

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, json, express

**EDIT**

Tengo una aplicacion Android hecha en Java, la cual quiero pasarle datos al recycler que he creado, los datos deben quedar asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para eso he creado la logica de llamada a la base de datos por medio de servidor express el cual devuelve los datos en formato JSON, el JSON que espero recivir es el sigiuiente:

```
[
    {
        "o_complemento_id":1,
        "nombre":"complemento1",
        "o_complementoline": 
        [
            {
                "o_complementoline_id":1,
                "nombre":"subcomplemento1"
             },
             {
                "o_complementoline_id":2,
                "nombre":"subcomplemento2"
             }
         ]
      },
      {
        "o_complemento_id":2,
        "nombre":"complemento2",
        "o_complementoline": 
        [
          {
            "o_complementoline_id":3,
            "nombre":"subcomplemento1"
          },
          {
            "o_complementoline_id":4,
            "nombre":"subcomplemento2"
          }
        ]
      }  
    ]
```

Porque del lado del android lo voy a pasar a clase JAVA la cual muestro a continuacion:

```
public class o_complemento {
    private Long o_complemento_id;
    private String nombre;
    private Integer minimo;
    private Integer maximo;
    private Long o_producto_id;
    private List<o_complementoline> o_complementolineList;

    //getter and setter
}
```

EL problema es que en el servidor express tengo separado las consultas de **complemento** y **complementoline**, los mostrare para mejor comprension:

```
router.get('/complemento/obtener', (req, res) => {    
    const { o_producto_id } = req.query
    
    if ( !o_producto_id ) {
        
        return res.status(500).send('datos vacios')
    
    } else {
        
        o_complementoController.obtener(o_producto_id).then(data => {

            if (typeof data === 'undefined') {
                
                return res.status(500).send('no se encontraron datos')

            } else {

                //console.log(data)
                res.json(data)

            }

        })
        .catch(err => {

            console.log(err)
            return res.status(500).send('error al ejecutar la consulta')

        })
    }
});
```

**o_complementoController**

```
module.exports = {

    obtener(o_producto_id) {
        
        return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
            conexion.query(query.obtener(o_producto_id), function (error, results) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error)
                } else {
                    resolve(results)                    
                }
            })
        }) 
    },

    
}
```

**query**

```
module.exports = {
    obtener(o_producto_id) {
        var sql = 
            `SELECT o_complemento_id, created, createdby, updated, updatedby, isactive, nombre, minimo, maximo, o_producto_id
            FROM o_complemento 
            WHERE isactive = 'Y' AND o_producto_id = ${o_producto_id}
            ORDER BY NOMBRE ASC`

        return sql
    }
}
```

**Resultado de la consulta en el navegador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**complementoline**

```
router.get('/complementoline/obtener', (req, res) => {    
    const { o_complemento_id } = req.query
    
    if ( !o_complemento_id ) {
        
        return res.status(500).send('datos vacios')
    
    } else {

        o_complementolineController.obtener(o_complemento_id).then(data => {

            if (typeof data === 'undefined') {
                
                return res.status(500).send('no se encontraron datos')

            } else {

                res.json(data)

            }

        }).catch(err => {

            console.log(err)
            return res.status(500).send('error al ejecutar la consulta')

        })

    }
});
```

**o_complementolineController**

```
module.exports = {

    obtener(o_complemento_id) {
        
        return new Promise(async ( resolve, reject ) => {
            conexion.query(query.obtener(o_complemento_id), function (error, results) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error)
                } else {
                    //console.log(results)
                    resolve(results)
                }
            })
        })    
    },
}
```

**query**

```
module.exports = {
    
    obtener(o_complemento_id) {

        var sql = 
        `SELECT 
        o_complementoline_id, created, createdby, updated, updatedby, isactive, nombre, costo_extra, is_costo_extra, o_complemento_id, isradio, ischeck, o_producto_id
        FROM o_complementoline
        WHERE o_complemento_id = ${o_complemento_id} 
        AND isactive = 'Y'
        ORDER BY nombre ASC`
        
        return sql
    },
}
```

**resultado en el navegador**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces lo que se me ocurrio es que desde el controlador que se llama *o_complementoController* generar las dos consultas e iterar los json devueltos para poder ejecutar la consulta y obtener los datos de *complementoline*
**o_complementoController**

```
const conexion = require("../database/ConexionMysql")
const query = require("../querys/o_complemento")
const queryLine = require("../querys/o_complementoline")

module.exports = {

obtener(o_producto_id) {
    
    return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
        conexion.query(query.obtener(o_producto_id), function (error, results) {
            if (error) {
                reject(error)
            } else {
                var customJson = "[\n"

                for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        
                        customJson +=  "{\n"
                            customJson +=  "\"o_complemento_id\":" + results[i].o_complemento_id + ",\n"
                            customJson +=  "\"nombre\":" + results[i].nombre + ",\n"
                            customJson +=  "\"o_complementoline\": "
                            customJson +=  "\n["
                                conexion.query(queryLine.obtener(results[i].o_complemento_id), function (error, resultsLine) {
                                    if (error) {
                                        reject(error)
                                    } else {
            
                                        if (typeof resultsLine === 'undefined') {
                                        
                                            console.log("error")
                                            return res.status(500).send('no se encontraron datos')
                            
                                        } else {
                                            for (let j = 0; j < resultsLine.length; j++) {
                    
                                                customJson +=  "{\n"
                                                    customJson +=  "\"o_complementoline_id\":" + resultsLine[j].o_complementoline_id + ",\n"
                                                    customJson +=  "\"nombre\":" + resultsLine[j].nombre + ""
                                                customJson +=  "\n},"
                                            }
                            
                                        }
            
                                    }
                                })
                            customJson += "\n]"
                        customJson += "\n},"
                     
                }
                customJson += "\n]"
                resolve(customJson)
                
            }
        })
    }) 
},
}
```

Pero que es lo que sucede al ejecutar como se me ocurrio: que los datos del *complementoline* no se muestran en el JSON que estoy construyendo, si pongo un `console.log(customJson)` dentro del segundo `for` aparecen los datos que el JSON se esta llenando, pero cuando vuelvo hacer la impresion al final de las llamadas osea ya para devolver como respuesta aparece como muestro a continuacion:

```
[
  {
    "o_complemento_id":1,
    "nombre":"complemento1",
    "o_complementoline": 
    [
      *aqui no aparecen datos, pero el segundo for si*
    ]
  },
  {
    "o_complemento_id":2,
    "nombre":"complemento2",
    "o_complementoline": 
    [
        *aqui no aparecen datos, pero el segundo for si*
    ]
  },
]
```

Los querys no son de importancia mostrarlos solo son las consultas a la base de datos.

Utilizo mysql (no mysql2) de node js

Comment: Que contiene la variable `resultsLine`? PD: que mala practica andar generando un `json` manualmente a punta de concatenaciones... porque no creas mejor un objeto y si lo necesitas convertir a JSON, usas `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @Pipe la variable contiene el resultado de la consulta a la tabla detalle del complemento... Si se a lo que te refieres pero dado el caso que estoy planteando no he encontrado otra manera de hacerlo porque necesito extraer los datos del jsob que devuelve el mysql

Comment: Me refiero es.... Que tipo de dato o estructura contiene esa variable? Se entiende perfectamente que es el resultado de la consulta, pero que formato tiene?

Comment: Es decir... si pone un `console.log(resultsLine)` que le muestra?

Comment: @Pipe es un JSON, el resultado de la consulta

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en que estás usando un función asíncrona dentro del `for`, por lo tanto es muy probable que al terminar el `for` ninguna de las consultas se haya terminado de ejecutar y por esta razón siempre le salgan vacías. Eso lo podrías solucionar usando async/await. Te debería funcionar algo así:

```
obtener(o_producto_id) {
        
        return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
            conexion.query(query.obtener(o_producto_id), function (error, results) {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error)
                } else {
                    const customJson = [];
                    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        const customObj = {
                            o_complemento_id: results[i].o_complemento_id,
                            nombre: results[i].nombre;
                            o_complementoline: []                           
                        }
                        
                        let resultsLine;
                        
                        try {               
                            await resultsLine = conexion.query(queryLine.obtener(results[i].o_complemento_id))
                            
                            if (typeof resultsLine === 'undefined') {
                                //Esto se me hace raro aquí, pero igual lo dejo porque está en su código inicial
                                console.log("error")
                                return res.status(500).send('no se encontraron datos')          
                            } else {
                                for (let j = 0; j < resultsLine.length; j++) {
                                    customObj.o_complementoline.push({
                                        o_complementoline_id: resultsLine[j].o_complementoline_id,
                                        nombre: resultsLine[j].nombre
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        } catch(error){
                            reject(error)
                        } 
                        
                        
                    }
                    resolve(JSON.stringify(customJson))                    
                }
            })
        }) 
    },
```

Comment: voy a probar tu respuesta

Comment: En la linea de codigo `resultsLine = conexion.query(queryLine.obtener(results[i].o_complemento_id))` si hago un `console.log(resultsLine)` no devuelve ningung valor..., creo que la version del modulo mysql no permite esa sintaxis, he investigado mas y la version mysql2 para node al parecer permite esa sintanix

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, faltaba un `await`... Pero de igual manera, como no conozco como funciona esa funcion de `conexion.query` ni `queryLine.obtener`, estoy haciendo suposiciones

Comment: Editare la publicacion, porque no logro resolver, con el await ahora me da erro, pido de tu ayuda veo que estas dispuesto, necesito salir de este problema

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el problema se debe a las consultas que se están realizando asíncronamente, tal como mencionaron anteriormente, para solucionar este problema puedes apoyarte de async/await, pude observar que te lo sugirieron anteriormente pero no se esta implementando de manera correcta.

Me tome la liberta de pulir el código para que quedara correctamente y fácil de entender:

```
    obtener(o_producto_id) {
        return new Promise( async ( resolve, reject ) => {
            try {  

                let results = await conexion.query(query.obtener(o_producto_id));
                const customJson = [];
                
                for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    const customObj = {
                        o_complemento_id: results[i].o_complemento_id,
                        nombre: results[i].nombre;
                        o_complementoline: []                           
                    }
                                       
                    let resultsLine = await conexion.query(queryLine.obtener(results[i].o_complemento_id));   
                    for (let j = 0; j < resultsLine.length; j++) {
                        customObj.o_complementoline.push({
                            o_complementoline_id: resultsLine[j].o_complementoline_id,
                            nombre: resultsLine[j].nombre
                        });
                    }
                }
                resolve(JSON.stringify(customJson))                    
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Espero haber podido ayudarte.

Saludos.

Comment: Te di punto por tener la buena intencion de ayudarme, ya logre solventar el problema, efectivamente tenia que ver con la parte ambos sugieren, al final agregue el paquete **sync-mysql** para poder tabajar de manera sync en el buclo for